# param is missing or the value is empty: {:user_id=>9}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have looked at questions like this one but I could not figure out how to solve it. I made several unsuccessful attempts. I get this error "ActionController::ParameterMissing in PropuneresController#new
param is missing or the value is empty: {:user_id=>9}" when visiting `http://localhost:3000/users/9/propuneres/new` .

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/show'

  devise_for :users

  get 'static/home'

  get 'static/despre'

  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    resources :propuneres
  end

  root to: 'static#home'
```

propunere.rb

```
class Propunere < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :propuneres


end
```

propuneres/new.html.erb

```
<h2> Propunere Nouă </h2>

<%= form_for @propunere, url: user_propuneres_path(@propunere), html: { method: :get } do |f| %>
  <ul>
  <% @propunere.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :titlu %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :titlu %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

propuneres_controller.rb

```
 before_action :prop

def new

    @propunere = Propunere.new()


end

def create
    @propunere = Propunere.new
    @propunere.titlu = params[:propunere][:titlu]
    @propunere.body = params[:propunere][:body]
    @propunere.user_id = params[:propunere][:user_id]
    @propunere.save
    redirect_to propunere_path(@propunere)
end


def index
end


private 



def prop
    params.require(user_id: current_user.id).permit(:titlu, :body,)

end


end
```

I think there are at least two things that I am doing wrong.
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the form, you must assign the user to url (if you want to use as nested resource)

```
user_propuneres_path(@user, @propunere)
```

At the controller (you tag this question as Rails 3, I assume you are not using the gem 'strong_parameters'), then you can remove the method `prop` and use this code for new and create:

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @propunere = @user.propuneres.build
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @propunere = @user.propuneres.new(params[:propunere])
  if @propunere.save
    redirect_to user_propunere_path(@user, @propunere)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: it gave me undefined method "propunere" in @propunere = '@user.propunere.build' -probably. I changed it to '@user.propuneres.build' and it worked.. hmm.. . Thank you!

Comment: It's my typo, because user has_many :propuneres. I'll edit and fix.