# .each loop returns []. Form / controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have RoR 4.2.0beta. (Although it s irrelevant as this is a beginer problem).

My form does not insert in the database the "propuneres" that I am creating trough it. And as a result they do not show in the index page when I get redirected to it. They show up when I create them through the console.

```
  class PropuneresController < ApplicationController

before_action :prop_params

def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @propunere = @user.propuneres.build



end

def create
    @user= User.find(params[:user_id])
    @propunere = @user.propuneres.new(params[:prop_params])
    @propunere.save
        if @propunere.empty?
            render 'new'

        else 
        redirect_to user_propuneres_path    
        end
end


def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @propunere = @user.propuneres(params[:prop_params])
end


private

    def prop_params
    params.require(:propunere).permit(:titlu, :body)
    end


end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h2> Propunere Nouă </h2>

<%= form_for @propunere do |f| %>
  <ul>
  <% @propunere.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>


  <p>
    <%= f.label :titlu %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :titlu %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2> Propuneri: </h2>

<% @propunere.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.titlu %>
    <%= p.body %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend naming classes/methods/variables etc. in English. What's worse, you mixed English `User` class name with Romanian `Propunere` class name in one application.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. U're right, it's not like someone who doesn't understand english will look over my code. I made it pointlessly inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cloned your [repo](https://github.com/bog306/P-notworking), here's the problem: in `new.html.erb` you had

```
<%= form_for @propunere, url: new_user_propunere_path(@user, @propunere), html: { method: :get } do |f| %>
```

Both the url and the method are wrong. `user_propuneres_path` will give you the correct url for the create action and the correct method is `:post`, not `:get`. This is why you never reached the `create` action.

You also need to change from `@propunere = @user.propuneres.new(params[:propunere])` to `@propunere = @user.propuneres.new(prop_params)`, otherwise you'll get a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` exception.

You can see all the routes in the app by running `rake routes` in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you. You probably mean rake routes? :P

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its relevant, but you have code

```
@propunere.save
        if @propunere.empty?
            render 'new'

        else 
        redirect_to user_propuneres_path    
        end
```

Object @prorunere will never be empty, since you have 
`@propunere = @user.propuneres.new`, which assigneds `user_id` to your `@propunere` object and
`render 'new'` will never be rendered, therefore you wont see any validation errors and never find out why your record wasnt created

Also since you have that piece of code, and dont see errors, this is what most like broke your code

`@user.propuneres.new(params[:prop_params])` - you should use your permitted params, so it'd look like

`@propunere = @user.propuneres.new(prop_params)`

Comment: point well taken. made the changes. the problem is still there. Thank you

Comment: can you post console log here? For your create action

Comment: I think it skips the create action since I could not find it in the log. (true that it s my first time in there) I found the index action where I get redirected after submitting the form - is this a problem? 
Started GET "/users/10/propuneres?utf8=%E2%9C%93&propunere%5Btitlu%5D=Test22&propunere%5Bbody%5D=Foo+xd&commit=Create+Propunere" for ::1 at 2014-12-01 17:07:43 +0200
Processing by PropuneresController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "propunere"=>{"titlu"=>"Test22", "body"=>"Foo xd"}, "commit"=>"Create Propunere", "user_id"=>"10"}
 Part2 below

Comment: [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mPropunere Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "propuneres".* FROM "propuneres" WHERE "propuneres"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 10]]
  Rendered propuneres/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 433ms (Views: 421.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

Comment: found create
Started POST "/users/2/propuneres" for ::1 at 2014-12-01 08:03:20 +0200
Processing by PropuneresController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sO4dHCShlVL2gdgOiEA2Guh4/ZeEq6KLYnOEvYvtcY0lbDi4Xc65AjfN9CZFo+e/DZWVOL+9GGH50WEBrXtizA==", "propunere"=>{"titlu"=>"asdasd", "body"=>"fdsfasdfdas"}, "commit"=>"Create Propunere", "user_id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]

Comment: [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 36ms

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/propuneres_controller.rb:14:in `create'

Comment: it jumps the create action (it does not appear in the newly generated logs) :|. Because I don't have show but only index? (it doesn t sound right)

Comment: Checked your code, make sure in your create action you have following
`@propunere = @user.propuneres.new(prop_params)`

Comment: you have error - `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`, which is permitted attrs related

Comment: I have only 1 instance of that error in the log. Considering the amount of attempts, that does not seem as the central issue. Is there any way to have someone look over the whole app? Any services or preferably volunteers as I currently can't afford to pay someone.

Comment: you can upload it to github and post link here. Thats easy way somebody to check your code

Comment: This is the repository for the code about which I posted originally there might be some commented lines https://github.com/bog306/P-notworking. It took me so long because I unsuccessfully tried to rewrite it from scratch (not nesting the resources).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the params in your index action:

```
@propunere = @user.propuneres
```

and it would be more logical to write it in plural since you have many of them.

---

*Edit:*

As Avdept suggested your create action should look like this:

```
 def create
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @propunere = @user.propuneres.new(prop_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @propunere.save
       format.html { redirect_to user_propuneres_path(@user), notice: 'Your propunere has been saved' }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Yeah avdept answers shows what's broken in your create action.

Comment: "param is missing or the value is empty: propunere"

Comment: I had this other (probably related) issue today (2nd post :( I'm trying my best not to post) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218681/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-user-id-9/27220425#27220425

Comment: the error above "param..." is given to me when I try to view the form.

Comment: Oh yeah that's probably because you haven't put the user in the form try: form_for([@user, @propunere])

Comment: it skips the create action. I can't find it in the dev. log.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any validations for the Propunere model? Maybe the model is invalid. You can use 
the `create!` method instead of `create` for testing, because it will throw an exception if the object cannot be saved. Also try `puts @propunere.inspect` before persisting it and check that the contents of the object are ok, the output will be shown in the development log.

Comment: No validations. only belongs_to :user. It totally ignores the create action. I tried, the action itself is missing from the log. I also tried binding.pry with the pry gem and it doesn't get to it.